# What happens if the output of a 74LS05 IC is connected to the input of a 74LS04 IC?

Tags: ttl

Explain what would happen if I connected the two ICs?

Comment: how connected? We'll need much more information. Also, describe what you've researched so far. These two ICs have names and datasheets, so you're not really starting from zero when **drawing a schematic** to add to your question to clarify what you're asking!

Answer (score 0):

You'll get the expected behavior, but with less noise immunity for the "going high" transition of that shared node. And probably more random jitter on that same edge.

Comment: thank you for your answer

Comment: @EvertonJunior Please come back and mark the answer when you're allowed to.